# how to check if json has this object in android

Tags: android, json, object

I use asynctask to get json data from remote url but sometimes this url return errors in json data like this :

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: RNN.NES",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 803
   }
}
```

in doInBackground, i check if there an error by json ..

if(true) { cancel asynctask and show toast with message i use

```
cancel(true)
```

but when i try to enter invalid url that contain error object, it doesn't see condition and force stop app

this is my code :

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            db.open();
            try {
                // Creating JSON Parser instance
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(params[0]);
                // addPageData(params[0]);

                if (json.has("error") == true) {
                    Log.e("error", "true");
                    toastMsg = "This username is invalid";
                    cancel(true);
                } else {

                    name = json.getString("name");
                    Log.e("error", name);
//                  category = json.getString("category");
                    fid = json.getString("id");
                    if (db.checkPage(fid)) {
                        toastMsg = "This page is already added";
                        cancel(true);
                    }

                    String picture = json.getJSONObject("picture").getJSONObject("data").getString("url");
                    picName = downloadImage(picture, fid);
                }

                db.closeDatabase();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
       @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(context, toastMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

jsonParser.java

```
package com.engahmedphp.facebookcollector;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // ==============================================================================
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        // try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        // DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // // HttpFeed httpFeed = new HttpFeed(url);
        //
        // HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        //
        // HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        // HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        // is = httpEntity.getContent();

        try {
            URL newURL = new URL(url);

            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) newURL.openConnection();
            is = con.getInputStream();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        // DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // // HttpFeed httpFeed = new HttpFeed(url);
        //
        // HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        // HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        // try {
        // httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        //
        // } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // } catch (IOException e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        // }

        try {
            // HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();

            // System.out.println(json);
            // System.out.println(httpEntity);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

it consider it doesn't contain error object then he move to do in else clause and force close

**this is my logcat .. i think it contains some infe maybe useful for you**

```
10-06 15:04:45.539: E/JSON Parser(7183): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
10-06 15:04:45.539: W/System.err(7183): org.json.JSONException: No value for name
10-06 15:04:45.539: W/System.err(7183):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
10-06 15:04:45.539: W/System.err(7183):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
10-06 15:04:45.539: W/System.err(7183):     at com.engahmedphp.facebookcollector.General$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(General.java:148)
10-06 15:04:45.539: W/System.err(7183):     at com.engahmedphp.facebookcollector.General$MyAsyncTask.doInBackground(General.java:1)
10-06 15:04:45.539: W/System.err(7183):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-06 15:04:45.539: W/System.err(7183):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-06 15:04:45.539: W/System.err(7183):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-06 15:04:45.539: W/System.err(7183):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
10-06 15:04:45.539: W/System.err(7183):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
10-06 15:04:45.539: W/System.err(7183):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
10-06 15:04:45.589: W/dalvikvm(7183): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400207d8)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:234)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.bindString(SQLiteQuery.java:182)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:48)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1454)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1338)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1293)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1373)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at com.engahmedphp.facebookcollector.DAOPages.getPageData(DAOPages.java:183)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at com.engahmedphp.facebookcollector.General.getPagePrefs(General.java:180)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at com.engahmedphp.facebookcollector.General.insertPageAndSetAlarmAndPrefs(General.java:207)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at com.engahmedphp.facebookcollector.General$MyAsyncTask.onPostExecute(General.java:113)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at com.engahmedphp.facebookcollector.General$MyAsyncTask.onPostExecute(General.java:1)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
10-06 15:04:45.679: E/AndroidRuntime(7183):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here in your JSON parser:

```
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
```

You are somehow passing a completely empty string into the object json, so it throws a JSONException.

Since you are using a static member for jObj, and your catch block above doesn't set it to null to indicate that there was an error, you are returning the last valid jObj from this method from any instance of JSONParser, so `json.has("error")` might return false.

I can't see any good reason for you to be storing jObj as a static member, so I would just change it to a local variable declared right before the code I quoted above. Then in your catch block I quoted above, return null after logging the error.  And in your `doInBackground` method, you can change the if statement to this:

```
if (json==null){
    //Log whatever kind of error could cause this, toast user, and cancel(true).
} else if (json.has("error")) {
    ...
```

Comment: thank you pal .. it works now but one thing is remaining .. when i do it for first time the app is forced stop but if i do it after one valid it works fine

Comment: this is the error : FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Comment: thank you .. i got it .. i used your solution by putting return null in first try and catch .. the error was in HttpURLConnection try/catch block

Comment: checked as right answer .. thank you very very much my friend